# Redirect URL with Chrome Remote Debugging Android Devices

Tags: google-chrome, debugging, url, redirect, testing

How can i redirect an URL with Chrome Remote Debugging Android Devices?  like [Requestly Chrome extension](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/requestly-redirect-url-mo/mdnleldcmiljblolnjhpnblkcekpdkpa) on desktop.

Comment: Not sure but maybe this could be helpful - https://medium.com/@hackupstate/using-charles-proxy-to-debug-android-ssl-traffic-e61fc38760f7

Comment: I found Progress `Telerik Fiddler Web Debugger`  and Configure it for Android. Extern network must be opened in new tab to trust connection.